# use matlab to handle pajek .net file?

Tags: matlab, file

I have a .net file which is in pajek format. Now I was thinking to use matlab to do the analysis of the data in this file. After searching online, I found a toolbox in matlab with name SBEToolbox. Considering installing this toolbox to the matlab might be a bit time-consuming, since I do not have administrative access to my pc currently. Do you have any better idea to use matlab with pajek .net file? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: If this is a third-party toolbox you shouldn't need admin access to install